# Need Infinite chart board with react-zoom-pan-pinch

Tags: css, reactjs, react-chartjs

I have created a flow chart using npm package `react-zoom-pan-pinch`

Problem :

The chart has a limit on the left and top side, and it seems infinite in the right and bottom side.

Is there any option using which I can extend the chart in all the four sides ?

The packages has many options including zoom, pan, pinch, etc.
I tweaked many of them, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which type of chart it is, bar, pie, histogram, timeline?

Comment: Forgot to mention, It is a flow chart

Comment: "extend the chart in all the four sides" Please eleborate if you want the zoom to work for all 4 sides, while pinching in or zoom in?

Comment: If I zoom out the chart, I can not extend my chart in left and top side after a limit @HaiderAliAnjum

Comment: limitToBounds default(true)...
limitToWrapper default(false)... try using these 2 props as it restricts zoom limit and scale to its bounds mentioned int he props. and also to the wrapper as its bounds are also provided.

Answer (score 2):

Set the property [`limitToBounds`](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/docs-props--page) to false:

```js
<TransformWrapper limitToBounds={false}>
  <TransformComponent>
    ...
  </TransformComponent>
</TransformWrapper>
```